# iPhone optimized 2-page "app" (website)

Tags: html, iphone, ios, css

I would like to create a website that acts like an app. It's super simple, but I still can't figure it out how to get it to work...

It's basically an image that is going to show when you launch the app from your homescreen (I need to somehow make the address & nav bar disappear). When you click on the image, it's supposed to show the next image.

I tried with this line of code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />

<!-- this is the part responsible for hidding the bottom bar -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/template/engage.png"/>
```

and the images are coded like this

```
    <a href="xxx.html">
<img src="xxxx.png"/>
</a>
```

But the problem is that the images are not size-adjusted to the iphone screen, they become much larger so you have to scroll to see the whole picture.

Also, whenever the image link is pressed a new safari window opens and contains the safari nav bars & address field.

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can set a maximum width on your image in css to avoid the image being wider then the current window:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

You may want to consider using a css framework, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). It may help you make a responsive/mobile-friendly website a bit more easily, especially with their grid systems, and responsive ui elements.

Answer (score -1):

try in css style

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT
Sorry, I was in a hurry .)